# What are the default algorithms used in Optplanner-Quarkus in the school-scheduling example?

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I was reviewing the example of Optaplanner in Quarkus related to the school-scheduling problem. However, there is not setup any configuration file. In this case, what local search and heuristics algorithms are set up by default? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In optaplanner-quarkus, if there is no `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml` creates a `SolverConfig` from the classpath information. So it sets the `solutionClass`, `entityClass`, `constraintProviderClass`, etc. But it doesn't set the `phaseList` (= the heuristics).

In optaplanner-core, if the `SolverConfig` has no `phaseList` (= the optimization algorithms), it currently defaults to CH and then a LS, which would look like this in XML (*) :

```
<constructionHeuristic/>
<localSearch/>
```

A Construction Heuristic currently defaults to First Fit (Decreasing). LocalSearch defaults to Late Acceptance with change and swap moves.

(*) There is no XML if there is no solverConfig.xml in quarkus and even if there is a solverConfig.xml in quarkus, it is parsed at build time, not at runtime for performance reasons.